# Azure Application Insights - How to analyze exported data

Tags: azure, data-mining, azure-application-insights

I have about 350GB of exported data that dates back to last june from my application insights. How can i analyze it?

How can i tell the portal to look back into that data and not only the last 90 days?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use exported data to power portal UX. Export feature is for integration with 3rd party services/backup/audit purposes/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well you *could*, but you'd have to write all of it yourself, and there'd be limitations.

1. you'd have to do the export which you're doing
2. you'd have to write something to parse and import that data back into your application insights resource into a *custom schema* (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-import)
3. and then you'd have to write tools/queries to join between old data in the custom schema and current data in the ai schema, being careful to de-dup any items that are in both places.

you wouldn't be able to use most of the built in portal tools, as they don't know about the custom schema.  but analytics queries in tools like the analytics portal or workbooks could see both sets of data.